# What is Stryker referring to?

Tags: marvel, x-men

In *X-2: X-Men United*, Colonel William Stryker encounters Wolverine at the mansion.

> Wolverine? I must admit this is certainly the last place I'd expect to find you. How long has it been? 15 years? You haven't changed one bit. Me, on the other hand... Nature.

As he says "nature", he taps the side of his forehead.

Is Stryker simply referring to the fact that he has aged naturally (with an oddly timed hand gesture), or does the tap of his forehead as he says this refer to something else?

Comment: Yes, just the fact that he has aged, which is natural, and Logan hasn't which is unnatural, therefore against nature, and therefore has to be eradicated, as he did with Logan's memories, which might be why he taps his temple.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

He's actually motioning to the wrinkles on his face to emphasize the fact that he's 'naturally' growing older with the passage of time. That is meant as a contrast and an indictment to Logan's agelessness and apparent youth. To Stryker, Logan is an abomination of nature.

Comment: “To Stryker, Logan is an abomination of nature.” Naw, he just jelly ’bout Logan’s smooth skin.

Comment: I haven't seen it confirmed anywhere, but I always assumed the word "Nature" was an embedded failsafe. Stryker doesn't seem to be the sort of man who would make a weapon like Wolverine without the ability to control it somewhat. And the claws sheathing seemed to be involuntary on Logan's part, which is largely why he seemed so shocked when he asked who Stryker was. It was never touched on in Origins, though, so who knows.